# I want to add random data to the table in html with jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, web

I'm having trouble doing my web developing homework because I don't know enough Java. It seems very easy, but it is little difficult task for me. I want to explain it.

My code will generate 5 random numbers, then display them on the page as a list. Each number generated will be between 1 and 100 and will have a variable name. After this, the code will generate a table with 4 columns and 5 rows. Variable names of the generated numbers will be written in the first two columns randomly. In the third column, a random mathematical operation will appear. In the fourth column the result will be displayed. After this, you will create a mathematical function by yourself and give the results to that function as parameters the code will calculate the result of the function and mod 10 will be applied to the result. The final result will be shown to the user. Below that, there will be 10 links which are labeled from 0 to 9. If the user clicks on the correct link, then the page will navigate to your own personal page, otherwise user will be redirected to a page that displays the result is wrong.

[image: taskimage]

```
    <h2>Random Table</h2>
<TABLE>
<% for(int row=1; row <= 5; row++) { %>
    <TR>

<%      
List<Integer> sayilar1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int random = (int)(Math.random() * 50); 
        sayilar1.add(random);

    %>
        <TD> (<%=random%>)
        </TD>
         <% } %>

<% for(int row2=1; row2 <= 5; row2++) { %>
<%      
List<Integer> sayilar2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int random2 = (int)(Math.random() * 50);    
sayilar2.add(random2);
    %>
          <TD>
          <%=random2%>
        </TD>
     <% } %>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: What servlet container are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Given this is an assignment, I am not sure I can fully help you, but I could get you started.

Your code shows the result of one value being printed out for each row.

You want to have something similar to the picture, I'd set it up this way.

```
<%@ page import ="java.util.Random" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>

<style>
    table,th,td{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <%
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Create a collection of operations
        // Create a collection of variable names
    %>

    <h2>Random table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First var</th>
            <th>Second var</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
        <% for(int row=1; row <= 5; row++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% /* Random variable name goes here */ %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% /* Random variable name goes here */ %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% /* Random operations goes here */ %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% /* Random result goes here */ %>
                    <% /* Hint... use rand.nextInt(maxValue) */ %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need some clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

To ease your problem you need to decompose it for each step.

> My code will generate 5 random numbers, then display them on the page
>   as a list. Each number generated will be between 1 and 100 and will
>   have a variable name.

Create a class to fit your needs.

```
public class Variable {
    int value;
    String name;
    public Variable() {}
    public Variable(int value, int name) { this.value = value; this.name = "v"+name; }
    public void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

Generate your 5 random variables between 1 and 100 and store it with a name.

```
ArrayList<Variable> variableList = new ArrayList<>();
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 1 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
    variableList.add(new Variable(rand.nextInt(100)+1, i));
}
```

Create another class to fit row constraints in your table (missing operator and result function).

```
public class Operation {
    Variable variable1;
    Variable variable2;
    int operator;
    public Operation() {}
    public Operation(Variable variable1, Variable variable2, int operator) {
        this.variable1 = variable1;
        this.variable2 = variable2;
        this.operator = operator;
    }
    public Variable getVariable1() {
        return this.variable1;
    }

    public void setVariable1(Variable variable1) {
        this.variable1 = variable1;
    }

    public Variable getVariable2() {
        return this.variable2;
    }

    public void setVariable2(Variable variable2) {
        this.variable2 = variable2;
    }

    public String getOperatorSign() {
        String operatorSign = "";
        if (operator == 1) {
            operatorSign = "+";
        }
        else if (operator == 2) {
            operatorSign = "-";
        }
        else if (operator == 3) {
            operatorSign = "*";
        }
        else { // operator == 4
            operatorSign = "/";
        }
        return operatorSign;
    }

    public Integer getResult() {
        int result = 0;
        if (operator == 1) {
            result = variable1.getValue()+variable2.getValue();
        }
        else if (operator == 2) {
            result = variable1.getValue()-variable2.getValue();
        }
        else if (operator == 3) {
            result = variable1.getValue()*variable2.getValue();
        }
        else { // operator == 4
            result = variable1.getValue()/variable2.getValue();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Fill your new list fitting your table with 5 values.

```
ArrayList<Operation> tableList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
    Variable variable1 = variableList.get(rand.nextInt(5));
    Variable variable2 = variableList.get(rand.nextInt(5));
     // not zero so random int +1 to get [1;4] instead of [0;3]
    tableList.add(new Operation(variable1, variable2, rand.nextInt(3)+1));
}
```

You have your table now, pass it into request attribute or so and then iterate over it in your JSP to make your layout.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" 
         isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First var</td>
            <td>Second var</td>
            <td>Operator</td>
            <td>Result</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${tableList}" var="row">
            <tr>
                <td>${row.variable1.value}</td>
                <td>${row.variable2.value}</td>
                <td>${row.getOperatorSign()}</td>
                <td>${row.getResult()}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Of course this can be improved (enum for operation etc. ...).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. İm working on these codes , i hope i will make it.

Comment: @BarisOZER You're welcome. Have you reached to get through your problem with this answer?